# why don’t we see snap id in Dashboard Ec2 ->Volumes( Snapshot column) although Snapshot exist in Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I can view the volumes and associated snapshots in console for few volumes i can't see snapshot id

Ec2-Console

Name VolumeID Size VolumeType IOPS Snapshot Created

test1 vol-1234 20GiB gp2 100/3000 snap-344012 jan 12

test2 vol-4564 20GIB gp2 100/3000 ? jan 13

for both volumes snapshot exists in console under EBS-> Snapshots

My question why dont we see snap id for volume test2 even though snapshot exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snapshot shown in the console is the snapshot the volume was *originally created from* -- not a snapshot of the volume itself.

If a volume is created blank (not from a snapshot), no snapshot is shown here.